# Can you add devices to an ad-hoc distribution without re-creating the IPA?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to distribute an app to an unspecified number of testers. I don't currently know how many will be wanting access, and therefore don't have their UDID's. From what I've read on the subject, you need to create an IPA that's signed to the devices (or to a provisioning profile that contains the devices) that are permitted to access it, or something like that?

My question is can you add devices to an IPA after it has been created?

I was intending to create a website for distribution, and add the devices as and when I receive the ID's. I don't want to go and re-create the IPA each time if I can help it.

Comment: You have to recreate the ipa as by definition it's a zip file with signed app and provisioning profile. You might leave the build process of app out and automate the rest, but you *have to* create a new ipa for every new device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use TestFlight.com for test ipa distributions. This feature is available there. Check [this link](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829818-adding-more-testers-to-a-build-).

If you are developing your own distribution portal, then you need to write scripts for resigning the ipa with new provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks. I went with TestFlight in the end, seems like the easiest way to handle this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add those UDID of the new device and then add them to your provisioning profile and then create an ipa file with that profile.

You can't directly add the new device UDIDs to an ipa file.

This is for the security purpose by APPLE. By this no one can install the application in to their device without the direct permission of the developer.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. You have to recreate IPA again.
As @sarwar said testflight will help.